# How to make uniform illumination in a image using openCV in python or how to enhance illumination in non-uniformly illuminated image

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I have an image to segment but illumination is non-uniform. So, how do I make it uniform to segment the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use adaptive equalization algorithm such as [CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html). Here is a minimal working example:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('original.jpg')
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
b = clahe.apply(image[:, :, 0])
g = clahe.apply(image[:, :, 1])
r = clahe.apply(image[:, :, 2])
equalized = np.dstack((b, g, r))
cv2.imwrite('equalized.jpg', equalized)
```

[image]